# Can't open specific website from multiple devices (desktops, phones using satelite)

Tags: web, mobile, dns

I have an unusual problem that no one seems to understand or be able to solve.

10 days ago I connected my domain (on Yahoo Small Business) giladcohen.com with a new website host/builder, Sequarespace, following 15 years when this domain had been hosted by Dynamod.

The new website seems to open properly at giladcohen.com on every device in the world except for my home's 4 computers and 2 iPhones, even when the phones are far from home using satelite.

All parties (Squarespace - site provider; Yahoo - domain provider; Verizon Fios - internet provider for our home internet and phones) ran multiple tests and say that all is working on their ends.

Steps that we're tried so far:

1. Erasing all cache and site data from various devices.
2. Reinstalling browsers and installing new ones.
3. Rebooting the router.
4. Changing the IP to a new one by the internet provider.
5. Running trace route on my site and others that are hosted by Squarespace and use a third-party domain (all show the same on my computer: Only two lines, one is Verizon Fios and the second is Squarespace's general address).

   Needless to say, giladcohen.com had opened properly on all these devices until 10 days ago, which I switched my website host from Dynamod to Squarespace.

I'd appreciate any leads!

Thanks in advance,
Gilad

Comment: "I'd appreciate any leads!" Some: 1) you are paying two providers for domain and hosting, did you ask them for help? 2) you should use appropriate forum, as your question is offtopic here since not related to programming. [su] or [webmasters.se] **MAY** be good for your question, but you need to read their help section to make sure your question fits 3) on cases like yours, the first step is to check DNS configuration. At least https://dnsviz.net/d/giladcohen.com/dnssec/ shows things are fine, so the problem is either on hosting or on network access

Comment: Thanks for replying, Patrick. My apologies for posting in the wrong forum, I will move my question. Yes, I've spent many hours with all three providers, who've also ran many DNS testings and found, as you did, that all seems fine. I also believe the problem is with either hosting or network access, but no one can identify what the problem is or suggest how to solve it.